# When my app is in background, push notifications are handled only if I touch the top notification banner

Tags: ios, push-notification

I've implemented

```
application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:
```

to store data in my app when a push notification is received.

However when my app is in background and I receive a notification, the data is stored only if I touch the notification banner appearing on top:

[image]

Instead, if I touch the app icon to reopen it, the content of the notification is not stored:

[image]

Since I'm receiving the notifications only when I use the distribution profile, I'm not sure if `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` is invoked only when I push the notification banner on top.

I thought it is always invoked at the time a notification is received, and not after a user action on the device.

**UPDATE**.
I don't know if this can help but, just to let you know, I haven't implemented any of these methods:

```
– applicationDidEnterBackground:
– applicationWillEnterForeground:
- applicationDidBecomeActive:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found out why. From documentation:

> If the action button is tapped (on a device running iOS), the system
>   launches the application and the application calls its delegate’s
>   application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method (if implemented); it
>   passes in the notification payload (for remote notifications) or the
>   local-notification object (for local notifications).
>
> If the application icon is tapped on a device running iOS, the
>   application calls the same method, but furnishes no information about
>   the notification.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html

However, I'm wondering if there is a way to load the payload even if the app has been re-opened by touching the icon.

Comment: I know it's been a while, but have you managed to detect/load the payload even if the app was opened by tapping the icon instead of the notification?